# W10 Thread Ordering Service

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Does anyone know if the Thread Ordering Service is available in Windows 10 (or other recent versions) and if so, how is it enabled?  The <avrt.h> functions would be extremely useful for a real-time multi-threading application I am writing on but the Thread Ordering Service is required to use them and there is very little useful info on the web about it.

Comment: Why are you asking? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-ordering-service) say nothing about its removal

Comment: The reason I ask is because it doesn't appear in my list of services and I can't find any reference to it in the registry.